# Source of a Dynamic Programming Algorithm for Finding the Maximum Independent Set in a Graph of Treewidth k

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms, trees, dynamic-programming

On the Wikipedia page of [Tree decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition), there is a dynamic programming algorithm for finding the maximum independent set in a graph of treewidth $k$.

> - For a node $X_i$ of the tree decomposition, let $D_i$ be the union of the sets $X_j$ descending from $X_i$.
> - For an independent set $S\subset X_i$, let $A(S,i)$ denote the size of the largest independent subset $I$ of $D_i$ such that $I \cap X_i = S$.
> - Similarly, for an adjacent pair of nodes $X_i$ and $X_j$, with $X_i$ farther from the root of the tree than $X_j$, and an independent set $S \subset Xi \cap Xj$, let $B(S,i,j)$ denote the size of the largest independent subset $I$ of $D_i$ such that $I \cap X_i \cap X_j = S$.
> - We may calculate these $A$ and $B$ values by a bottom-up traversal of the tree:
>   $$
>   \begin{aligned}
>   &A(S, i)=|S|+\sum_{j}\left(B\left(S \cap X_{j}, j, i\right)-\left|S \cap X_{j}\right|\right) \\
>   &B(S, i, j)=\max _{S^{\prime} \subset X_{i} \atop S=S^{\prime} \cap X_{j}} A\left(S^{\prime}, i\right)
>   \end{aligned}
>   $$

I'm curious about the source and proof of this algorithm. Up to now, I have consulted many articles such as

- [Bertelè, U., & Brioschi, F. (1972). Nonserial Dynamic Programming.](https://doi.org/10.2307/3007942),
- [Arnborg, S. (1985). Efficient algorithms for combinatorial problems on graphs with bounded decomposability — A survey. BIT Numerical Mathematics, 25, 1-23.](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01934985),
- [Bern, M.W., Lawler, E.L., & Wong, A.L. (1987). Linear-Time Computation of Optimal Subgraphs of Decomposable Graphs. J. Algorithms, 8, 216-235.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0196-6774%2887%2990039-3),
- [Bodlaender, H.L. (1988). Dynamic Programming on Graphs with Bounded Treewidth. ICALP.](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-19488-6_110)
- [Arnborg, S., & Proskurowski, A. (1989). Linear time algorithms for NP-hard problems restricted to partial k-trees. Discret. Appl. Math., 23, 11-24.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X%2889%2990031-0),
- [Bodlaender, H.L., & Koster, A.M. (2008). Combinatorial Optimization on Graphs of Bounded Treewidth. Comput. J., 51, 255-269.](https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl%2Fbxm037),

but none of them seems to be consistent with this algorithm. Does anyone know the source of the algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: I have a certain confusion on the Wiki's algorithm, can you please explain it a bit? Because I saw many papers talking DP on nice tree decomposition rather than general tree decomposition. I suppose the wiki one is the general form

Comment: @Edee I did a demonstration of the algorithm for an example, see [td4mis.pdf](https://github.com/CarlossShi/img/blob/master/.pdf/td4mis.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check it later. I am doing combinatorial opt, hopefully we can talk more later.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this algorithm oringinated from the following paper:

- [Arnborg, S., and A. Proskurowski. 1989. “Linear Time Algorithms for NP-Hard Problems Restricted to Partial k-Trees.” Discret. Appl. Math.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X89900310)

This paper actually introduced a general dynamic programming approach which solves many problems such as dominating set, vertex cover and independent set. The notion of partial $k$-tree in this paper is equivalent to a graph of treewidth at most $k$.

---

If you are only interested in the DP for independent set on graphs of bounded treewidth, I suggest to read chapter 7 of the followinng text book named *Parameterized Algorithms*, which will be more readable.

- [Cygan, Marek, Fedor V. Fomin, Lukasz Kowalik, Daniel Lokshtanov, Daniel Marx, Marcin Pilipczuk, Michal Pilipczuk, and Saket Saurabh. 2015. Parameterized Algorithms. 1st ed. Springer Publishing Company, Incorporated.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-21275-3)